# How to change the json structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm developing React in my applications. is that any possible to convert the data as per the expected.

the data which i got from the backend is given below

```
[
{close: 37382,
date: "2021-01-22",
f_date: Fri Jan 22 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) ,
high: 39251,
low: 10555,
open: 11111},
{close: 37382,
date: "2021-01-22",
f_date: Fri Jan 22 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), 
high: 39251,
low: 10555,
open: 11111},
{close: 37382,
date: "2021-01-22",
f_date: Fri Jan 22 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
high: 39251,
low: 10555,
open: 11111}
]
```

need the format above data as by the following expected data
[{x : f_date,y:[open,high,low,close]}..]

expected format

```
[
 {x : Fri Jan 22 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),y :[11111,39251,10555, 37382]},
 {x : Fri Jan 22 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),y :[11111,39251,10555, 37382]},
 {x : Fri Jan 22 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),y :[11111,39251,10555, 37382]},
 {x : Fri Jan 22 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),y :[11111,39251,10555, 37382]},
]
```

how to convert the json data by expected format.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `.map` and the exact format you provided:

```
data.map((d)=>({x: d.date, y: [d.open, d.high, d.low, d.close]}))
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I could understand you can just iterate over the input data and create a new list in the expected format like this :

```
 expectedData = []     
    inputData.forEach( (input) => { 
    expectedData.push(
       {x: input.date, y: [input.open, input.high, input.low, input.close] }
       );
    });
```